# Xampp Apache will not run because of Port

Tags: wordpress, apache, xampp, skype, ports

I am trying to lauch Apache with Xampp, but it says always that the Port is already used or blocked. I reasearched the Web and found some Information about Skype. I tried to change the Port from Apache htttd.conf File i changed Port 80 to 81 and Port 443 to 444 and it failed again. Second time i tried the Skype version and turned off the using of port 443 and 80. Tried to start Apache again, didnt work. So I am here now, i hope someone can help me, btw here is the Error Message coming:

```html
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
22:08:10  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
22:08:10  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
22:08:10  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
22:08:10  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
22:08:10  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
22:08:10  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
22:08:14  [Apache]  Problem detected!
22:08:14  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 7008!
22:08:14  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
22:08:14  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
22:08:14  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
22:08:14  [Apache]  Problem detected!
22:08:14  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 7008!
22:08:14  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
22:08:14  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
22:08:14  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

Comment: I'm guessing you need to run it as root or admin. What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 8

Comment: Could you try to run XAMPP before Skype? Log out at Skype, end remaining processes, start XAMPP, start Skype. I had this problem as well and starting XAMPP before Skype works for me while vice versa does not.

Comment: I already triet that, i deleted Skype and it still dont works... :/

Comment: Is IIS enabled? You can check this in the System Control Panel at "Programs and Features" and "Turn Windows features on or off" in the left sidebar. If there is a checkbox at "Internet Information Services (IIS)", uncheck this and try to run XAMPP after a restart. IIS uses port 80 as well, so this might be a problem.
(Names may be different, I don't have an English Windows machine)

Comment: i have no clue about windows 8 but in xp there was a way to check services and ports using the GUI, check out command prompt and netstat, but i remember windows 7 had the IIS issue as well...